# Export/import to Excel with combo box

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

I'm still struggling with my scenario.  I have looked everywhere for a solution and cannot find a solution.  I am using C# and ASP.NET and I need to export data to an Excel spreadsheet.

I have a list of applications that contains Application objects.  Each Application object has a status ID.  When I export these applications to Excel then I need a column with a drop down/combo box in it.  In this drop down/combo box should be a list of all the statuses from the database.  And then I need the status to be selected to that of the application's status ID.

Another question is also with regards to the above scenario.  When the user downloads the Excel document then the user can change the status of each application by selecting a different value in the drop down.  I will need to upload this spreadsheet and loop through the rows and get the values of the columns and the value of the selected item in the drop down/combo box.  How would you do this?  Is this possible?

I may not use COM components, so I tried to go with EPPlus or NPOI (it does not have to be these 2) but it doesn't seem like they support my scenario.  How would I be able to achieve my scenario?  Once again, it doesn't have to make use of EPPlus and NPOI.  Working examples would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Brendan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a template in NPOI?  When I want to export complex spreasheets with NPOI, I create a XLS document to use as a template, and fill in the data via C#.

Comment: No I haven't.  Have you by any chance got some sample code for me please?  I have a deadline for tomorrow so my time is really limited to go and experiment now.  If you can just give me some sample code then I can probably take it from there.

Comment: Here is a link to an example where I used NPOI to load a template.  It's not a direct match, but the general concept in loading a template should be clear.  http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/05/npoi-excel-template/

Comment: Thanks.  I have a sample of how to do it.  But what I am looking for is how to select an item from the drop down based on what my applications state is.  I have a list of all the states in a drop down, I need to select the item of my apllication state.  How would I do this programmatically?

Comment: You should consider making a macro in Excel for this... set the macro to autorun and your drop-down value will be set.  Here is a link about setting drop-down list values.  http://en.allexperts.com/q/Excel-1059/2010/3/Referring-value-combo-box.htm

Comment: Ok cool let me see what I can do regarding this.  Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

No need of macro at all. C# itself will do it for you.
Here i have a Demo for importing from a excel(no matters it is 2003/2007) to gridview and exporting gridview (EDITED/changed) data to a new EXCEL FILE. Try it. Works 100%

What you need to do is : create a folder named "Files" inside your Web Application and keep your excel file inside "Files" folder. If your datasource (from where your grid is populated)is other than excel, then no need of the above folder.You can write your own code inside the btnImport_Click().
Here is your .aspx page :

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ImportFromExcelToDatasetAndGridviewAndExport.aspx.cs" Inherits="ImportFromExcelToGridViewWebApp.ImportFromExcelToDatasetAndGridviewAndExport" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div>
        <b>Please Select Excel File : </b>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadExcel" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import From Excel" OnClick="btnImport_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#009933"></asp:Label><br />

        <asp:GridView ID="grvExcelData" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            onrowdatabound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"  HeaderText = "UserName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"  
                                     CssClass="css2"  Text='<%# Eval("UserName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" 
                                     CssClass="css2"  Text='<%# Eval("UserName")%>'>
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"  HeaderText = "Education">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEducation" runat="server"  
                                     CssClass="css2"  Text='<%# Eval("Education")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEducation" runat="server" 
                                     CssClass="css2"  Text='<%# Eval("Education")%>'>
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"  HeaderText = "Location">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server"  
                                     CssClass="css2"  Text='<%# Eval("Location")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" 
                                     CssClass="css2"  Text='<%# Eval("Location")%>'>
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="DrdDatabase" Width="100px" runat="server">
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DrdDatabase" Width="100px" runat="server">
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export To Excel" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is your code behind.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.Collections;

namespace ImportFromExcelToGridViewWebApp
{
    public partial class ImportFromExcelToDatasetAndGridviewAndExport : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private ArrayList ExcelData
        {
            get
            {
                object excel = Session["dropdownvalue"];
                if (excel == null) Session["dropdownvalue"] = new ArrayList();
                return (ArrayList)Session["dropdownvalue"];
            }
            set
            {
                Session["dropdownvalue"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DrdDatabase");
                foreach (string colName in ExcelData)
                    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(colName));
            }
        }

        protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
            string connString = "";
            string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(fileuploadExcel.FileName).ToLower();
            string fileBasePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(this.fileuploadExcel.FileName);
            string fullFilePath = fileBasePath + fileName;

            //Connection String to Excel Workbook
            if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fullFilePath +
                              ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
            }
            else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fullFilePath +
                             ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
            }
            if (fileuploadExcel.HasFile)
            {
                string query = "SELECT [UserName],[Education],[Location] FROM [Sheet1$]";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                //Assigning dataset table data to GridView Control
                Session["griddata"] = ds.Tables[0];

                System.Data.DataTable dtt = (System.Data.DataTable)Session["griddata"];  //griddata is the gridview data from another page        
                var res = (from f in dtt.AsEnumerable()
                           select f.Field<string>("Location")
                    );


                foreach (string s in res.AsEnumerable())
                {
                    alist.Add(s);
                }

                Session["dropdownvalue"] = alist;

                grvExcelData.DataSource = Session["griddata"];
                grvExcelData.DataBind();

                da.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }

        protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();

            dtExcel.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
            dtExcel.Columns.Add("Education", typeof(string));
            dtExcel.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
            dtExcel.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(string));
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grvExcelData.Rows)
            {
                string UserName = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtUserName")).Text;
                string Education = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEducation")).Text;
                string Location = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtLocation")).Text;
                string Location2 = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DrdDatabase")).Text;
                DataRow dr = dtExcel.NewRow();
                dr["UserName"] = UserName;
                dr["Education"] = Education;
                dr["Location"] = Location;
                dr["Select"] = Location2;
                dtExcel.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            CreateWorkbook(dtExcel, Server.MapPath("~/DownlodedFiles/Excel.xls"));
        }

        public static void CreateWorkbook(System.Data.DataTable dtExcelData, String path)
        {
            int rowindex = 0;
            int columnindex = 1;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wksheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkbook;
            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = false;
            wkbook = app.Workbooks.Add(true);
            wksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wkbook.ActiveSheet;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtExcelData.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    wksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dtExcelData.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                }

                foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows)
                {
                    rowindex++;
                    columnindex = 0;
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dtExcelData.Columns)
                    {
                        columnindex++;
                        wksheet.Cells[rowindex + 1, columnindex] = row[col.ColumnName];
                    }
                }

                app.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {

            }
            app.UserControl = true;
        }
    }
}
```